# JS buttons with max value

Tags: javascript

I wanted to create two buttons that increments value and stops at the max value changing the button's colour to red to indicate the button cannot be clicked anymore and has reached the max value, then a reset button to rest it all back to 0.
I have part of the code but tried adding the max value to the buttons and the reset button but its not working. so far this is what i have which basically increments the value by 1 with each click.can anyone help please?

```js
var button1 = 0;
var button1 = 0;

function onClick1() {
  button1 += 1;
  document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML = button1;
};

function onClick2() {
  button2 += 1;
  document.getElementById("button2").innerHTML = button2;
};
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="onClick1()">Click</button>
<p><a id="button1">0</a>
</p>
<button type="button" onClick="onClick2()">Click</button>
<p><a id="button2">0</a>
</p>
```

Comment: What have you tried that's "not working"?  We may be able to help fix that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum number in JS is `Number.MAX_VALUE`
so

```
var button = document.getElementById("button1");
var i;
var max = Number.MAX_VALUE;
//The loop
for(i = 0; i < max; i++) {
 button.textContent = i;
}
button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Comment: Yeah.. I can almost guarantee OP wasn't talking about the JS max value. More of "a max value"

Comment: So just change max to the value needed

Answer (score 0):

Set maximum vars and a logic check.

```
var button1 = 0;
var button1 = 0;

var max1 = 25;
var max2 = 25;

function onClick1() {
    if (button1 < max1){
        button1 += 1;
        document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML = button1;     
    }
};
  function onClick2() {
    if (button2 < max2){
        button2 += 1;
        document.getElementById("button2").innerHTML = button2; 
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks and how would I reset all the buttons together?

Answer (score 0):

protip: use `textContent` not `innerHTML` since you are not altering the HTML content.

Simply add an if statement to your functions.

```
var buttonElement = document.getElementById("button1");
if (++button > maxValue) {
    buttonElement.style.backgroundColor = "red"; //grab button via variable, change color
} else {
    button1++;
    buttonElement.textContent = button1;
}
```

Going further, if you really want to tell them "stop clicking me!" simply disable the button when you change the color to red.